# iOS11.2 iPad landscape, static split view, new SearchController, SearchBar usage spacing issue

Tags: ipad, uisearchcontroller, spacing, searchbar, ios11.2

New to Xcode/Swift, learning to use new SearchController methods (nav item, not table header). Dev'ing iPad landscape static split view app and search works fine, but has following UI behavior:

This is the starting point (master list before pull down to reveal searchbar):
[master list before pull down to reveal searchbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U15iN.png)

Pull down works as expected:
[master list pulled down to reveal searchbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jneAq.png)

Search starts with added scopebar - still everything a go:
[search list with added scopebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iU0ky.png)

Cancel the search, and there is a space where the scope bar was (I can push up on the list, and it will snap back in place):
[cancelled search with unwanted space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iFFi.png)

And the fun continues! If I initiate a second search, the first row of the search list is partially covered by the scopebar:
[second search with first row partially covered by scopebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTw5d.png)

If I tap one of the other scope buttons, the search list presentation is corrected:
[scope change with correct search list presentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbFw0.png)

I have scoured SO, and not found this exact issue; I have found other posted issues where the searchbar/scopebar were not correctly displayed, but none with extra spacing.  I have tried various suggestions anyway, such as sizeToFit() in multiple places, adding/ignoring insets, turning various IB checkboxes on/off, and nothing is working - the changes only make it worse.  Any suggestions?

FYI - This is also posted in the Apple Dev Forums at https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/97536, and I have some code snippets there, along with a few responses (but no solution yet).